# What is the wrong with my makeView?

Tags: php, view, laravel

I keep getting errors on this line of code and I am not sure what the problem is?

Here is the route:

```
Route::get('/samples', 'TestsController@index');
```

Here is the controller line that is causing the error:

```
public function index()
{
  return $this->makeView('samples.create');
}
```

Here is the error: `Method [makeView]` does not exist.

Comment: Which framework do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with

```
public function getIndex()
{
    return View::make('samples.create');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
 public function index()
 {
      return $this->make::View('samples.create');
 }
```

You forgot the :: between make and View.

Answer (score 0):

Im not aware of a 'makrView' method, but this is how a view is traditionally rendered.

```
$templateVars = array('varOne' => $templateVariableOne, 'varTwo' => $templateVariableTwo);

return View::make('samples.create', $templateVars);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Laravel 4, you don't need $this to make a View in a controller.

```
public function index()
{
  return View::make('samples.create');
}
```

Also you got View and make the wrong way round.

Documentation here: http://laravel.com/docs/responses#views